# How exactly lithium metal is produced?

Tags: electrochemistry

Wikipedia and other sites say that lithium metal is produced by making the electrolysis of a mixture of half lithium chloride and half potassium chloride "at about 450°C"... What is the chemical reaction of this electro-chemical reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electrolysis is done as a molten salt.

$\ce{LiCl(liquid) ->[LiCl/KCl @ 400-460 C] Li(liquid) + 1/2Cl2(g)}$